# Putting HTML file on Heroku for facebook use

Tags: facebook, heroku

I am trying to use Heroku to host a few html pages for my facebook app.

The problem is i am not sure how i put the files on my Heroku and then get the link to the web html pages to use.

Could you anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is designed to host apps and is really not built to host single static pages.  It's possible to do: Heroku lists the following for creating a simple rack site: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby.

But to be honest I'd have to say there's probably better places to host a page, like creating a free blog on http://www.wordpress.com and using that.

Comment: I just created a free blog, but how do i create a plan html page?

Comment: And for heroku, could you give me an example of creating a html page and getting the link to the page?

Comment: The link in the answer provides a way to create a small site with static content.  You'll need an editor to create the file itself.

Comment: As far as the blog goes just create a page using the admin interface and visit it by clicking "visit site" link and copy the URL in the browser.

Comment: The type of html tags i am using wordpress keeps removing them.